# Show data obtained from a function and place it in a shortocode function

Tags: php, functions, parameter

I'm new I need to put a value obtained from a function and put it in my shortocode function if you can help me thanks

```
$a=4; // value obtained from another function

my_function($a);

function my_function($i){
$a=$i+1;
return $a;
}

add_shortcode( 'operation', 'my_function' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Why don't you just call the function inside the shortcode handler? This looks more like general PHP question.

Say we have a variable in our `functions.php` or wherever you define your shortcodes:

```
$another_var = doSomeFunctionThatReturnsData();
```

With modern anonymous functions, you can pass variables using the `use` keyword.

```
add_shortcode('operation', function (array $atts, ?string $content, string $shortcode_tag) use ($another_var): string {
    $out = 'The value of my variable is: ' . $another_var;
    return $out;
});
```

With ancient named functions as callbacks, you can access a variable in the global scope (defined outside and "above" your callback) by bringing it into your local scope (inside the body of your callback) by using the `global` keyword:

```
function shortcode_operation_handler(array $atts, ?string $content, string $shortcode_tag): string {
    global $another_var;
    $out = 'The value of my variable is: ' . $another_var;
    return $out;
}
add_shortcode('operation', 'shortcode_operation_handler');
```

Those words before variable names are types for the parameters (more on those [in the PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)). The type after the semicolon (`:`) in the function definition denotes [its return type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration).

**... or you can simply call the function inside your shortcode handler.**